# Why is magnetic field due to magnetization $M$ (net dipole moment per unit volume) of a material given by $B=\mu_0M$?

Tags: electromagnetism, magnetic-fields, magnetic-moment

(Magnetization $M$ of a sample is defined as the net magnetic dipole moment per unit volume.)

If, for example, the interior of a solenoid is filled with a material of non zero magnetization, the field inside solenoid will be greater than $B_0=\mu_0ni$

It will be $B=B_0+B_m$

where $B_m$ is the field due to the material of non zero magnetization ($M$) and is given by:

$B_m=\mu_0M$

Does this above expression have a proof or is it experimental?

(as per the book NCERT, for class 12)

Comment: no proof, it is the definition of $B_m$

Answer (score 0):

Saying that $B_m$ is the magnetic field due to the magnetization $M$ mathematically translates to the magnetostatic equations:
$$
\nabla\cdot B_m=0\\
\nabla\times B_m=\mu_0j_m
$$
with $j_m$ the electric current due to the magnetization given by:
$$
j_m=\nabla \times M
$$
You immediately get:
$$
\nabla\times B_m=\nabla\times (\mu_0M)
$$
so it is tempting to get rid of the curl to obtain your equation.

This would be too hasty as the equation is not always true. You would need to verify that $\nabla\cdot M=0$ as well. A physically relevant example where this fails is a finite sized magnetized object. Typically, there are magnetization fluxes at the boundaries or, more physically, surface currents. This gives an additional irrotational term in $B_m$.

Note that in your example, if the solenoid is infinite, there is no magnetization flux along the sides so the equation is valid.

Usually, this is often true within highly symmetric magnetized objects. Restricting the possible fields by symmetry, Ampere’s law can be sufficient to prove the equation.

Hope this helps.